# Django Migrate Operation Fails with error "the database system is in recovery mode"

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, database-migration

I was migrating an old project, but for some reason the migration always failed at this file, i tried executing just this migration file, still same error.

I have attached the command i used, the logs from the python terminal on the command and the logs from the database below.

The command used

```
python3 manage.py migrate content 0037_auto_20180618_1711
```

The Migration file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.1 on 2018-06-18 17:11
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('content', '0036_trivia_original_description'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='trivia',
            name='is_approved',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=32, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

The logs from the migrate operation

```
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 65, in execute
>     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
>         This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>         before or while processing the request.
> 
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 244, in apply_migration
>     state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py",
> line 129, in apply
>     operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py",
> line 215, in database_forwards
>     schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 514, in alter_field
>     old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py",
> line 112, in _alter_field
>     new_db_params, strict,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 683, in _alter_field
>     params,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 120, in execute
>     cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 80, in execute
>     return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 65, in execute
>     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94,
> in __exit__
>     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line
> 685, in reraise
>     raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 65, in execute
>     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: server closed the connection
> unexpectedly
>         This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>         before or while processing the request.
> 
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 213, in ensure_connection
>     self.connect()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 189, in connect
>     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
> line 176, in get_new_connection
>     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line
> 130, in connect
>     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
> 
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 12, in
> <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 363, in execute_from_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 355, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 283, in run_from_argv
>     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 330, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
> line 204, in handle
>     fake_initial=fake_initial,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 115, in migrate
>     state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
>     state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 244, in apply_migration
>     state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
> line 95, in __exit__
>     self.atomic.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py",
> line 267, in __exit__
>     connection.set_autocommit(True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 401, in set_autocommit
>     self.ensure_connection()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 213, in ensure_connection
>     self.connect()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94,
> in __exit__
>     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line
> 685, in reraise
>     raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 213, in ensure_connection
>     self.connect()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 189, in connect
>     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
> line 176, in get_new_connection
>     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line
> 130, in connect
>     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
```

The log in the postgresql database is following

```
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 15:19:32.361 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.062 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 100) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.062 UTC [1] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: ALTER TABLE "content_trivia" ALTER COLUMN "is_approved" TYPE varchar(32) USING "is_approved"::varchar(32), ALTER COLUMN "is_approved" DROP NOT NULL
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.062 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.062 UTC [97] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.062 UTC [97] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.062 UTC [97] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.063 UTC [101] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.064 UTC [1] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.090 UTC [102] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-01-27 15:19:32 UTC
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.175 UTC [102] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.184 UTC [102] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1B00C58
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.184 UTC [102] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1B00C90: wanted 24, got 0
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.184 UTC [102] LOG:  redo done at 0/1B00C58
postgres_1    | 2019-01-27 16:31:15.232 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Not sure why the particular SQL command fails.  `ALTER TABLE "content_trivia" ALTER COLUMN "is_approved" TYPE varchar(32) USING "is_approved"::varchar(32), ALTER COLUMN "is_approved" DROP NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a table that has a large amount of data in it, so altering the table is causing an operation that makes postgres run out of data.  If you don't need to preserve the data in the table, clear it out using a `truncate table` statement.  If you need to preserve the data, dump it to a file using `pg_dump`, clear it out, run migrations, and then reload the data.

Comment: the table has 0 entries in it